# Logging issue for function call in powershell-workflow

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

The issue I'm facing is logging the output of a function being called inside the powershell workflow into a logfile.

Tried using Out-File but it is not supposed to be used for logging a specific function call.

Any help on this would be great. Thanks in advance.

**Attached is the sample script regarding the issue:**

```
function test1{
    param (
    [String] $FileName)
    Write-Host "$FileName test1"
}

WorkFlow Sample { 
    $Files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Downloads\testDir' 
    Foreach -parallel ( $File in $Files ) {
        test1($File) #This function output should be logged
    }  
}

Sample
```

Comment: I also found a blogpost on how to write a logging function: https://blog.ipswitch.com/how-to-build-a-logging-function-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

To create a file you can do this: (`$outcome` being the variable containing the outcome of that function)

```
$outcome | Set-Content 'file.txt'`
```

or

```
$outcome > 'file.txt'
```

If there already is a file and you want to append:

```
$outcome | Add-Content 'file.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks Marthyn, this works for Write-Output and return statements in the function but in my case I even have Write-Host statements in the function which are not logged.

Answer (score 0):

[about_redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6) on Microsoft docs has quite a bit of information.

One of the problems you got is that you're trying to redirect `Write-Host`. Depending on your PowerShell version you might have more or less options available. Prior to version 5 you had to use something like `*>` or `Tee-Object` where applicable. With version 5, there are some new options available:

> Starting in Windows PowerShell 5.0, `Write-Host` is a wrapper for `Write-Information` This allows you to use `Write-Host` to emit output to the information stream. This enables the capture or suppression of data written using `Write-Host` while preserving backwards compatibility.
>
> The `$InformationPreference` preference variable and `InformationAction` common parameter do not affect `Write-Host` messages. The exception to this rule is `-InformationAction Ignore`, which effectively suppresses `Write-Host` output. (see "Example 5")

An easy option would be to use `Write-Output` instead of `Write-Host`. You won't be able to color it (easily) but in your current example you don't need to. In addition, depending on your use case, you could look into using [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-6) which might also be available.